# Message Handler not passing data to TextView

Tags: android, textview, hex, android-handler, ftdi

Title of this question might be incorrect as I am assuming this is the problem. I am new to both Java and Android and have been struggling on this for days.

I am trying to connect to an ECU (non OBD-2) via an FTDI cable, usb-to-go and an Android device.

I have based most of this code on the examples shown on the FTDI website using their Android D2xx.jar library, example code and by reading their documentation.

The problem I am experiencing is that the TextView "dataView" is not being updated at all. In Fact the following line shows an error of :  "The value of the local variable dataView is not used" - The TextView append line is not being seen due to it being in a separate thread? Or this possibly indicates to me that my implementation of a message handler could be incorrect or something similar?

In addition to this, the data from the ECU is expected in hex format , 6 bytes to be precise initially. So the second part of my question is is how to display the hex info in textView as hex in string format?

```
TextView dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView);


-----------------------------------------------------------
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (iavailable > 0) {

                dataView.append(String.copyValueOf(readDataToText, 0, iavailable));

            }
        }
    };



------------------------------------------------------------

public class readECUThread extends Thread {
        Handler mHandler;

        readECUThread(Handler h) {
            mHandler = h;
            this.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

            synchronized (ftDev) {
                iavailable = ftDev.getQueueStatus();

                if (iavailable > 0) {

                    if (iavailable > readLength) {
                        iavailable = readLength;
                    }

                    ftDev.read(readData, iavailable);
                    for (i = 0; i < iavailable; i++) {
                        readDataToText[i] = (char) readData[i];

                    }
                    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the object of the message. Something like msg.obj = readDataToText before you do mHandler.sendMessage(msg); and then reading it in the handleMessage method

Comment: No hoomi, not sure exactly how to do that so going over some tutorials in the hope I can work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple stupid error on my part in the 1st line of my originally posted code:

```
TextView dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView);
```

Should have just been :

```
dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataView);
```

Eclipse did not pick this up as an error so it had me scratching my head for a while. I now get data to the TextView field but in very strange characters (possibly Korean as it is a Samsung phone?).